# How to configure routing in angular 4 so that feature-modules routes will come in order as children?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-module

Project structure:

```
 /app
   app.module.ts
   app.routing.ts
   :
   :
   /dashboardModule
   /manage-productModule  
      manage-product.module.ts
      manage-product.routing.ts
```

In 'app.routing.ts'

```
[
  {
   path : '',
   loadchildren: 'loginModulepath/loginmoduleName#className'
  },
  {
   path : 'dashboard',
   component: dashboardReportComponent
  }
  {
   path : 'manage-products'
   loadchildren: 'manage-productModule-path/manage-product-moduleName#manageProductClassName'
  }
]
```

In the module: manage-products/ manage-product.routing.ts

```
 const manageProdRoute =
 [
  {
   path : '',
   component: manageProductListComponent
  },
  {
   path : 'detail',
   component: manageProdDetailComponent
  }
 ]
```

And,

```
 import:[ routerModule.forChild(manageProdRoute)]
```

**Goal:**

If user types `url:port/`  => it will redirect to `url:port/login/`
If user types/ click on link to go `url:port/manage-products`  => it will load `manageProductListComponent`

**Problem**

But when I'm trying to load `URL:port` to go to login page instead it loads `manageProductListComponent`. Even if I comment out `manage-product` section from `app.routing.ts` it behaves the same but if I mention all the children of all modules in detail in `app.routing.ts` then it works properly.

**Question**
What I need to do to keep all the module-based routing in individual `routing.ts` and import them in `app.routing.ts` so that they work *in order*?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code sample :-

```
[
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
{ path: 'login', 
   children: [
        { path: '', component: yourLoginComponent},
        { path: 'dashboard', component: your-dashboardReportComponent},      
   ]
},
{ path: 'manage-products', 
   children: [
        { path: '', component: your-manageProdDetailComponent},           
   ]
},
];
```

you have given empty pathmatch as **manageProductListComponent** which cause problem

```
{
   path : '',
   component: manageProductListComponent
 },
```

Comment: that is fine. but I'd like to keep featured module's routing in separate i.e. manage-product.routing.ts will supply the config to app.routing.ts

Comment: is there any way to tell routing configuration that `{
   path : '',
   component: manageProductListComponent
 },` is a child route under 'manage-products' route path ?